# How to override the default and remove any optional URL for an Area in Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

With an Area named "Administration" the URL is `~/Administration`, but how do you hide it without this default or optional ones? I want to call this Area something not related.

Have tried

```cs
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("/Administration", "/Index", "toothbrush");
```

This still had the option of using the default URL, and I would have to copy/paste this for all the pages in the Area(?).

Also tried

```cs
options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Administration", "/", pageRouteModel =>
{
    foreach (var selectorModel in pageRouteModel.Selectors)
        selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template = "toothbrush/" + selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
});
```

But this made the URL look like `~/toothbrush/administration`? And not sure if it is the correct way.

I appreciate your time and all help.

Comment: String.Replace? `selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template =  selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("administration", "toothbrush");`

Comment: @MikeBrind I didn't get that to work?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. If you don't want the area to be named Administration, why can't you just change the name of the folder?

Comment: @MikeBrind I can live with ~/whatever/administration/create etc, or I could rename the folder. But I would like to know how to override the default URL for an Area (or folder) entirely whitin Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the "Administration" part of the URL with, say "Toothbrush", you can use a PageRouteModelConvention:

```
public class ToothbrushPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        if (model.RelativePath.StartsWith("/Areas/Administration"))
        {
            var selector = model.Selectors.First(s => s.AttributeRouteModel.Template.StartsWith("Administration/"));
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("Administration/", "Toothbrush/");

        }
    }
}
```

You register this in Startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new ToothbrushPageRouteModelConvention());
}
```

See more here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions